# Why does clipping a raster using a shapefile lead to CRS mismatch and 0 values on edges?

Tags: pandas, gis, raster, shapefile, rasterio

Why does clipping a raster using a shapefile (both originally have the same CRS) lead to the clipped raster not having the same CRS but instead it is assigning 0 to the edges for the x and y axes. I am trying to clip a raster for crop production using a GAMD shapefile using the mask fucntion from rasterio.

Tried assigning the CRS to the clipped raster but it does not have that attribute but it still doesnt give the same latitude and longitude that I expect.